# What is this "[]" here doing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is an extract from my textbook.

I have a question about the use of [] here in `window.history[type]()`. I can tell that it's separating the object name(window) and the variable(type) so that they can be recognized as separate things but is there a name for this use of []? I performed a google search but nothing came up.

```
$(function() {
//omitted
['back', 'forward'].forEach(function(type) {
  $('.' + type).click(function() {
    window.history[type]();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `[]` notation is used when you try to access property using a variable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: this is the same as doing window.history.back() or window.history.forward(), however, since type is dynamic, you must access the back or forward property using bracket notation

Comment: `type` is inside [] because in this case you are trying to read the property of object window.history that the variable `type` holds. If you remove `[]` and use `.` instead it will actually try to read the property `type` inside object `window.location` but you want to read the string that the variable holds. In this case `back` and `forward`.

Comment: There is no var to access to with square bracket notation in example code, so as is, it is an array with a forEach loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: @Mosè Raguzzini, a bracket access is done with `window.history[type]()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **property/method access using bracket notation**.
In Javascript, you can access the properties of an object using the dot notation:

```
myObj.prop
```

Or the bracket notation:

```
myObj['prop']
```

When you dynamically construct the properties, however, you have no choice but to use bracket notation:

```
window.history['forward']()
```

is the same as

```
window.history.forward()
```

Here you are iterating on the `forward` and `back` properties, and the bracket notation is used to call the functions from their string names on `window.history`.

Here is [the doc linked by @Teemu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: There is no var to access to with square bracket notation in example code, so as is, it is an array with a forEach loop.

Comment: I think the question was about the access done on `window.history`, which holds the `forward` and `back` functions() called by `window.history[type]()`, is there something I didn't interpret well?

Comment: No they missed it. Don't worry, your answer is fine.

Comment: >Here you are iterating on the `forward` and `back` properties, and the bracket notation is used to call the functions from their string names on `window.history`. I finally understood what this code is doing after reading your answer. Thanks so much!